# Is there any reason that I cannot use parametric equations to write a single equation for a 3 dimensional line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

The gist of my problem is this: I was wondering if by solving two of the 3 parametric equations for the square root of $t$, which would look like
$$
\begin{split}
\left(\frac{x - x_1}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} &= t^{\frac{1}{2}}\text{ and}\\ 
\left(\frac{y - y_1}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} &= t^{\frac{1}{2}}, 
\end{split}
$$
and by manipulating the third equation to look like
$$
\frac{z - z_1}{c} = t^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot t^{\frac{1}{2}} ,
$$ could I substitute the first two equations for $t^{\frac{1}{2}}$ into the third to derive a single equation for a 3d line?

Side note, I apologize for not using the special math notation, as I have yet to become familiar enough with it.

Comment: The resulting equation will be true at every point on the original line, but it will also be true at many new points that are not on the original line, so it's not an equation for the line.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.